# Command "make:auth" is not defined laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6.2.0 and command `make:auth` is not defined in my terminal. Is there any solution to that? Noted that Composer has already been updated.

Comment: `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Please use this command "php artisan ui vue --auth", because laravel 6 remove php artisan make:auth command.

Answer (score 19):

In the Laravel 6 application that the make:auth command no longer exists.

Laravel UI is a new first-party package that extracts the UI portion of a Laravel project into a separate [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui)  package. The separate package enables the Laravel team to iterate on the UI package separately from the main Laravel codebase.

You can install the `laravel/ui` package via composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

### The `ui:auth` Command

Besides the new ui command, the `laravel/ui` package comes with another command for generating the auth scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

If you run the `ui:auth` command, it will generate the auth routes,  **HomeController**, **auth views**, and **app.blade.php** layout file as like `make:auth`

---

If you want to generate the views alone, type the following command instead:

```
php artisan ui:auth --views
```

---

If you want to make auth in **react** and **vue** js you may use this commands.

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

`php artisan ui vue --auth` command will create all of the views you need for authentication and place them in the `resources/views/auth` directory

The `ui` command will also create a `resources/views/layouts` directory containing a base layout for your application. All of these views use the Bootstrap CSS framework, but you are free to customize them however you wish.

More detail follow. [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/running-make-auth-in-laravel-6) & [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-routing)

### Simply you've to follow this two-step.

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.2"
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:auth` Laravel 6 has removed `make:auth` command and authentication scaffolding has been moved as a separate package named [laravel/ui](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui)

*The command to implement Auth is as follows:*

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

This command will install a ***layout view***, ***registration*** and ***login views***, as well as routes for all authentication end-points. A HomeController will also be generated

Here you can read about [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases) and [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) and also here you can read about laravel/ui in laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend)

Answer (score 0):

`Make:auth` command has been removed from laravel 6.x .
Instead you should use 
vue auth in laravel 6.x version .

Check this link for more information .

[Laravel auth in 6.x](https://laravel-news.com/running-make-auth-in-laravel-6)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using reactjs for your ui

    `$ composer require laravel/ui
    $ php artisan ui react --auth
    $ npm install && npm run dev
    $ php artisan serve`